# Partition type cannot be changed using PowerShell

Tags: partitioning, powershell

The partition is now a Basic data partition. However, when I execute this PS command:

```
Set-Partition -DiskNumber 3 -Number 41 -GptType "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"
```

It fails and shows this error message:

> Set-Partition : Invalid Parameter Activity ID:
> {27cd8457-2f32-4fc4-9a24-1e5fc8f8fa67} En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
> Set-Partition -DiskNumber 3 -Number 41 -GptType "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2- ...
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-Partition],
> CimException
>    FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 5,Set-Partition
> ```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a typo in the command for the `-PartitionNumber` where you use `-Number` instead. So just use the `-PartitionNumber` parameter with the [set-partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-partition?view=win10-ps) PowerShell command as listed below.

### PowerShell

```
Set-Partition -DiskNumber 3 -PartitionNumber 41 -GptType "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Set-Partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-partition?view=win10-ps)

Comment: @SuperJMN.... If for some reason it is not the `-PartitionNumber`, you might need the `-MbrType` in it's place but I'm not 100% certain. If you determine that is the case, let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly. The main point is that the `-Number` parameter is not correct more than anything.